# Align Fonts in CSS so that they appear to be vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create an HTML structure (in React JS) which looks like this:
[image]

Here is the code for the same:

```
<div className="FullSizeContainer">
        <div className="Section-01-Header">
        <TabularComponent />
        </div>
        <div className="Section-02-Header">{DashboardDetails.Heading}</div>
        <div className="Section-03-Header">
        <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +DashboardDetails.LogoName} className="Customize-Logo" alt="Loading..."></img>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS as well:

```
.FullSizeContainer
{
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.Section-01-Header
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100%/6);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #437E37;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;

}

.Section-02-Header
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100%/1.5);
  background-color: #4557A1;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: unset;
  text-align: center;

}
.Section-03-Header
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100%/6);
  background-color: #4557A1;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: unset;

}
.Customize-Logo
{
  height: 8rem;
  width: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

As you can see the numbers seem to be bottom aligned and the reason for this is the two different font sizes (The one for "Welcome to Your Dashboard" and the other for the numbers) as far as I see. Can someone tell me a good way to make them align vertically with respect to the middle heading?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using margin-top/margin-bottom. Setting either one to auto on the Section-x-Header divs should center it vertically. Additionally you could use this formula to calculate a percentage to set either one to: 50 - [(div height)/(2 * container height)]*100 = % for margin-top and margin-bottom.  Is the text align being applied to the child components (specifically the TabularComponent). You may need to apply the text-align to the TabularCompenents style as well. (this is my first answer on here, I hope it's helpful)

Comment: Umm... can you just use my snippet to indicate in which CSS segments should I add this? I already tried margin-top/margin-bottom but that didn't help.